# Java printing out a component as a image while window hidden

Tags: java, printing, jcomponent

Is there anyway to take of a component while the window is hidden?
Like minimized or something.
I need to create a bufferedimage from it.
But cant get it wroking while window is hidden.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Comment: Do you mean how to get it to draw to a BufferedImage while minimized or how to actually initiate the drawing?

Comment: like make a screenshot from a component while the jframe is minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is possible to create [BufferedImage](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm) from Top-Level Container or their [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) but you have to (before that)

- Container could be visible on the screen
- Container could be packed by calling `pack()`;

Comment: It's a jpanel where i want a screen from

Comment: please look at @camickr http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/, to avoid any of missinterpretation(s)

Comment: I'm using that now but if i minimize the window the class will not take a screenshot from the jpanel. :/

Comment: @Jeffrey Gearsoffun that reason why I linked Graphics2D tutorial, because every Components returns Graphics / 2D and link to (@camickr) best of workaround here